# django post_save call from within sending Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have a pretty simple model that works:

```
class Badge(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, help_text="Name for Badge")
    category = models.ForeignKey(BadgeCategory, help_text="Category for badge")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=32, help_text="A brief description")
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=format_badge_name)

    signals.post_save.connect(create_badge, sender=Badge)
```

I know my create_badge function in signals.py works. If I send it without a value for sender, it says the sender is a LogEntry object. I want/need to reference some of the instance information in the post_save script like below:

```
def create_badge(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    from userinfuser.ui_api import UserInfuser
    from django.conf import settings

    if created:
        api_key = settings.API_KEY
        api_email = settings.API_EMAIL

        ui = UserInfuser(api_email, api_key)
        ui.create_badge(instance.category.name, instance.name, instance.description, instance.file.url)
```

Where can I call my post_save call so it's aware of Badge (I'm assuming this is the fix?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Without specifying `sender` as in `signals.post_save.connect(create_badge, sender=Badge)`, all `model.save()` calls would cause the `create_badge()` to be called

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just connect the signal with sender=Badge **after** Badge is defined, tested example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import signals

def create_badge(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print "Post save emited for", instance

class BadgeCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Badge(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, help_text="Name for Badge")
    category = models.ForeignKey(BadgeCategory, help_text="Category for badge")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=32, help_text="A brief description")

signals.post_save.connect(create_badge, sender=Badge)
```

Test shell session:

```
In [1]: category = BadgeCategory(name='foo')

In [2]: category.save()

In [3]: badge = Badge(category=category, name='bar', description='test badge')

In [4]: badge.save()
Post save emited for Badge object
```

Comment: I've tried that, and while it doesn't error out, it's also apparently not calling the signal.

Would it be possible to call all of this from inside __init__?

Comment: I'm confused by your vocabulary. You don't *call* a signal: you either **connect** it to a receiver, either **emit** it (which will *call* all connected receivers). Anyway, I added a tested/working example to my answer.

Comment: I'm sure the confusion is from my lack of formal knowledge (especially with signals).  If I place the signal.post_save.connect command within the Model class it's called, but I get a dependency issue (Badge is undefined within Badge). The only other example I have for this is related to User Profiles, and the sender is the User model so I haven't run into this before. 

If I place the signals.post_save.connect command outside of the Badge model it doesn't seem to be called at all.

Comment: you were exactly right the whole time. I had a simple error in a variable I was passing into the receiver.