# How to achieve cascade model updates with django?

Tags: django

Having the following models:

```
class Comercio(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)

class Menu(models.Model):
    comercio = models.ForeignKey(Comercio, blank=False)
    # Other fields here
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Item(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, blank=False)
    # Other fields here
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

What would be the right approach to update "modify_date" on *Comercio* each time one of the associated Menus or Items change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the signals framework built into Django: [Doco found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/)

With it you can add actions on Model B that occur only on update or save of Model A. 
It's very nice stuff actually.

[Here is an old answer that has an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810202/django-post-save-call-from-within-sending-model)

Comment: I'm new to django and doesn't know about signals but I have the same issue of cascade update. Any help ?