# Django models : auto save

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have 2 class from my model

```
class APPLICANT_DATA(models.Model): 
    FIRST_NAME= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    LAST_NAME= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    MIDDLE_NAME= models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

and

```
class Applicant_status(models.Model):
    fkey = models.ForeignKey(APPLICANT_DATA)
    COMMENTS = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    date_of_app = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

how do i make my 'Applicant_status' to populate whenever a data in 'APPLICANT_DATA' is inserted?

Here is my views.py

```
def save_page(request):
form = application_form(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST':

    if form.is_valid():  

            emails = form.cleaned_data['EMAIL']
            mail = EmailMessage("Your activation and application code is: asdasd, do not show this to anyone", to=[emails])

            mail.send()
            cde = form.save(commit=False)
            applicant_status.objects.create(fk=cde.id)
            cde.save()



            return HttpResponseRedirect('verify')

else:
    form = application_form()

return render(request, 'frontend/apply.html', {'form': form})`
```

EDIT: My forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import APPLICANT_DATA
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class application_form(ModelForm):

FIRST_NAME = forms.CharField( max_length=20, label = ("First Name"),
. . .
class Meta:
    model = APPLICANT_DATA
    fields = ('FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', )
```

error is (1048, "Column 'fkey' cannot be null")

Sorry if this was a newbie question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use django signals to achieve this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/

Or you can manually save Applicant_Status with fk set to Application_Data you have just received in your view.

Comment: Can you add a brief example as a reference? I'm a bit of a beginner and i am overwhelmed thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810202/django-post-save-call-from-within-sending-model. You replace create_badge functionality with Applicant_Status save functionality.

Comment: So.. To manually save i'll just have to use 
`cde = form.save(commit=False)`
`Applicant_status.objects.create(fk=cde.id)`

I'm getting an error though

Comment: Paste you view function.

Comment: i have edited my question
thank you for answering guys T.T